# Movie/TV show Identification: What is the name of this sci fi movie, mutants, spaceship, military?

Tags: story-identification, movie, mutant

My memory is a bit fuzzy in what was the movie all about, I have been searching for this movie/tv show for some time. I can only remember certain scenes, but I assume the setting was on Earth and the movie might have been made during the 70s, 80s, or maybe during the 90s. I'm really iffy on the details so here it goes...

- At the end of the movie there was some sort of homeless bum (beard, messy hair, trenchcoat?), who if I remember correctly was also seen in the beginning. The bum carried a boombox, and by the end of the movie it is shown that the bum's chest was glowing green. (I remember this somewhat better the other details)
- The main character was on some sort of ship that got attacked, wore white jumpsuits?
- Big guns, possibly hover assisted, used by what seem to be a person with feline like eyes and vulkan like eyebrows
- May not be too sure about this, but there might have been Air Force soldiers in this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My bad, a boombox. Thanks.

Comment: Wait... the main character was a ship that wore clothes?

Comment: Main character was in some sort of ship